# Laravel Servererror

Tags: php, laravel

I've changed my root of my laravel project to: '/'. So I don't have to type public again and again.

But now my XAMP server is not working anymore. It's just telling me servererror. Also when I do php artisan serve it's telling me this error:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/local/index.php'
>   (include_path='.:') in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/local/server.php on line 21

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make sure there is no `.htaccess` file or an `index.php` file  in the root directory left from the original xampp files (htdocs) that redirects to `.../local/server.php`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the answer to the question, but the best way to prevent writing public, instead of changing the root document for the web server is to create a symlink to the public directory with your short name, example:

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs
ln -s project_longname/public project_shortname
```

and you will abe to go:

```
http://localhost/project_shortname
```

Before doing this, revert your document root back and make sure you use different name for the symlink and the actual path to the project

Also, note that paths are examples, but replace with yours, since I don't know your entire configuration

I hope it helps